# Is CakePHP's ACL capable of handling users belonging to many groups?

Tags: cakephp, acl

is CakePHP's ACL component capable of handling users belonging to many groups?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not out the box, no... and this thing requires to many chars.

Answer (score 0):

In my own quest parallel to yours, I have found these promising guides to how to implement many-to-many/HABTM user-group ACL in cakephp:

- [Ceeram's Authorize Plugin](https://github.com/ceeram/Authorize)
- [TinyAuth](http://www.dereuromark.de/2011/12/18/tinyauth-the-fastest-and-easiest-authorization-for-cake2/) and [some Q&A on its implementation](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/cake-php/RBIS95xNgQ4)
- [brett's guide on mrphp.com](http://mrphp.com.au/code/simple-auth-users-habtm-groups-cakephp) Note: I couldn't get this one to work in Cake2.x despite attempting [migration procedures](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-0-migration-guide.html); It might still work in older cake version though.